# failed to mkdir /usr/include/php/ext/raphf

Tags: sudo, chmod, pecl

I want to install pecl_http

but it told me:

> configure: error: Please install pecl/raphf and activate extension=raphf.so in your php.ini.

so I run
`pecl install raphf`

But it told me

> failed to mkdir /usr/include/php/ext/raphf

So I tried this:
`sudo chmod 777 ext`

but it said:

> chmod: Unable to change file mode on ext: Operation not permitted.

Is there someone can help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score -3):

You need to install PHP modules as root, unless the install root is writable by your user; i.e. `sudo pecl install ...`